# Codingbat java String 2 plusOut - "String index out of range - 1"

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to do the problem "plusOut" on codingbat in preparation for my upcoming Computer Science quiz, but I am having some errors.

This is the problem: http://codingbat.com/prob/p170829

This is the solution/code I am trying to use:

```
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - (word.length() - 1); i++) {
  if (str.substring(i, i + word.length()).equals(word)) {
    s += word;
  }
  else {
    s += "+";
  }
}
return s;
```

The error that I am getting is the "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" error that says "String index out of range: -1"

**UPDATE:**
I changed my code so that it doesn't give me that error but now whenever there are multiple occurrences of the string in the main string, it doesn't work.

The errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/imsrp.jpg

Comment: Please post your example data, I mean, what is the data you are putting in the method that give you that error... also if is possible put the full method's code

Comment: @Dazak Alright I just added that...

Comment: Post your new code (or modify the original one to show what you've changed it to.)

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Done...just take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, when you have found a substring, you then continue to iterate over the characters of the string that are part of the substring. You need to skip those characters, and restart at the end of the substring.

Another thing is that codingbat only tells you whether or not your code gives the right answers, but it doesn't tell you if it's well-written or efficient. You need a mentor or a good forum to do that (perhaps codereview.stackexchange.com). One thing I noticed about your code is that you are building a string in a loop. You should be using `StringBuilder` for that. If you are using an IDE, you should enable code inspection options that give you warnings about questionable practices. You can also use command-line tools, such as findbugs and checkstyle.

Here's my version:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ) {
    if (i + word.length() <= str.length() &&
            str.substring(i, i + word.length()).equals(word)) {
        sb.append(word);
        i += word.length();
    }
    else {
        sb.append('+');
        i += 1;
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

However, using substring() this way is not very efficient. You are creating many String objects and then throwing them away, just to search for the occurrence of a word in a string. It's better to use `String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`. Here is an alternative version (which probably has higher performance):

```
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
int i = 0;
int wordIndex = 0;
while ((wordIndex = str.indexOf(word, i)) != -1) {
    Arrays.fill(chars, i, wordIndex, '+');
    i = wordIndex + word.length();
}
Arrays.fill(chars, i, str.length(), '+');
return new String(chars);
```